# Tables for stable homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty} \wedge \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am wondering if there is any computation of stable homotopy groups of  $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}\wedge \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ in low dimensions? I would be very grateful for any reference.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{R} P$ equal $\mathbb{R} P^\infty$?

Comment: @Mark Grant yes

Comment: Upto how many dimensions?

Comment: @Prasit Something reasonable. Say, up to the same dimension that we know stable stems, at least at the prime $2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bob Bruner and Christian Nassau both have code that can compute the Adams charts efficiently.  For example, Bob has a chart for $\mathbb{R}P^2\wedge\mathbb{R}P^2$ at http://www.rrb.wayne.edu/cohom/index.html, and he might be able to do $\mathbb{R}P^\infty\wedge\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ with little effort if you asked him nicely.  But I don't know where you would find information about the Adams differentials.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not know of the charts. Meanwhile, I used some AHW-spectral sequence to do some computations in very low dimensions. From this computations, I learn that the differentials in this spectral sequence also could be very difficult to recongise/identify.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to chime in to plug my own Ext calculator (a joint venture with Dexter Chua). You can see an interactive calculation of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^4\wedge\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^4$ here:

[Ext chart here.](https://hoodmane.github.io/rust_ext/?data=eJztWcuu2jAQ3fcrrrz2gtjuQ9l2V6lSdbc3KHKDQZbyoEm4oory7_WjrkqLYTIBFlxWOPb4zMQzx5MjBtKqQm-1qvuOpC_kWXVN-apasqSk69QPkpKvUteEEln0uqlJOpDPTd317a7ov3R-QpYb9b2VeS0rZTbIlarMhpXspXkaMjeR-_1dZryYKV1vd70ZZ2Sf7JOM0Iw0W7uWLO1w1_tla1o0ar0248QsbFQdNrGMjDS2zCzmuHQGUVcM5oo5V-ewKDhwcSpwAQmcQ52xc84AbyYo8JyEc3YEjU1Pb-TMGaZUovlj02shOf6ODFNX0VT_HRefkuhz73jdsjk8BGDgIKwrB354SgLqLFLv7B_2zENL9hxzOZ48BmYx_3fFMeTip-_haI1zzD0cOW8Ej3GFwnE0jxQdx1S4gOQOjMYhRQfuNlFCHNBrFhbH9cEouQSmnUTeEkHUCBbHtMxInQkMq6O3MoK20YpF0DZarwLHJUAmwX0MgDU3Mo75NABhzY1M4O6faGwILvFzV_rRMmSHpXPBsOdhCQw9onEhrrloXIjUBCxrvdalckLRLT1_E3lX5ebHoZodqtWFWVrLslN-xkrGIciSlNHwxZZyGnpVKmi4BtL3NHyEeQPXfryBY2MwsLYfaOgp3sCRwhu4ZAYDa_uRhjr3Bi5D3sAdSjCwtp9GM650WTftnevexS11b3JL3bt46N470b3gGr25sAVHdll9D1Kuc9EeyvVNKNcJ5ALkDowGUq7gfnFz5To3sodyvUflOoFLV1eul9SaAsfxhzp8c-rwjzB0MBbF6r3-59bPrnWte_W00pWRhUZVyfKpala70qyOZBzHdwPi78zfNnZYyX2-UptWmSe-MIC_AAQJMQ4)

There's a list of other example modules that you can resolve here: https://hoodmane.github.io/rust_ext/

You can interactively add Adams differentials and it will propagate them using a few basic rules, but you'll mostly need to work them out yourself.